# Describing graph with constriants from physical world

Tags: python, graph, networkx, graph-theory

The graph nodes are datacenters with only two unique paths from street into them. In graph theory multiple edges don't take this constraint into consideration. e.g.

```
G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(2,5)
G.add_edge(1,3)
G.add_edge(3,5)
G.add_edge(1,4)
G.add_edge(4,5)
```

The above declaration automatically describes the graph edge to node relationship through 3 unique edges which defys the physical world constraint of only 2 possible path in/out of node 1 and node 5 respectively.

```
+----- 2 -----+
|             |
+----- 3 -----+
1             5
+----- 4 -----+
```

the above is more like the correct physical representation which I need to describe in graph as well but all I am getting is 3 unique edges from node 1 and node 5.

```
  +--- 2 ---+
 /           \
1----- 3 -----5
 \           /
  +--- 4 ---+
```

Can someone please enlighten me how can I define the physical world constraint of only 2 possible paths in/out of 1 & 5 (instead of the 3 that graph implementation is producing) by default. Thank you.

Comment: *"instead of the 3 that graph implementation is producing"* What graph implementation? How were the edges produced? In your example you added the edges manually yourself. Since you added 3 edges incident to node 1, then of course there are three edges out of node 1.

Comment: Thank you Stef, there are logically 3 edges mapped to 2 physical edges. that is why I have to put these edges as I did but I am unable to map them as I really want and that is why I asked the question :)

Comment: But what is the question? I really don't understand. What do you want to do? What do you mean by "define the physical world constraint"? What "graph implementation" are you referring to? What would the resulting graph look like?

Comment: Stef thank you for your interest. Allow me to explain, the real world node only has two possible paths in/out of the node. So if there are 3 logical edges in/out of such a node in graph it is shown as diagram 2. Reality is only one logical edge is mapped to south path to node 4 and two of the remaining logical edges should be mapped to a single north path as shown in diagram 1. Is there a a way to describe a graph per diagram 1 above? showing only 2 possible edges (mapped to many logical graph paths).

Comment: Stef in answering your question I just realized that by using edge_attribute I can easily define the 2 physical edge constraint overlay to 3 logical edge definition that graph definition comes with. Hence I am happy to report the problem is solved using edge_attribute. Thank you for making me think :)

Answer (score 0):

Realizing someone may look it up in future, so here is how I was able to describe my constraints...

```
G.add_edge(1,2, {overlap: '1_3'})
G.add_edge(2,5, {overlap: '3_5'})
G.add_edge(1,3, {overlap: '1_2'})
G.add_edge(3,5, {overlap: '2_5'})
G.add_edge(1,4, {overlap: ''})
G.add_edge(4,5, {overlap: ''})
```